# Login to drupal

Tags: drupal

I have issues logging into my newly installed drupal 6 website. I have installed a fresh copy of the drupal 6-19 and and haven't added any new modules yet.

When I enter my administrator user/pass and click login, The same first page is returned, with no sign of the reason of a login failure. When I login with an incorrect user/pass pair I get the appropriate errors.

I can't login to the system to see the reports. Is there any log file which I can review to trace the problem.

Comment: I'd guess that you'd get a much better response to this question by asking on the Drupal forums or mailing list.

Comment: so you see the login to the left? even after logging in? when you login it will always bring you to the main page but you will have your nav bar to the left changed from a login form to links to admin and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If it refusing to sign you in, check that cookies are enabled, otherwise you will get this behaviour. If in doubt, clear your cookies to start again.

Also double check that you don't have a dubious .htaccess in the drupal root folder, which may also cause this. You can try another login page at your-site-name/user as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have clean urls enabled?  If so and the web server isn't setup properly you can get into a situation where you can't get to any page other than the front page.  this is typically an issue with .htaccess or apache configurations files depending on how you're setting it up.  But the issues are typically with the rewrite rules in particular in either case.

You should be able to get to the admin page by using http://www.example.com/?q=admin/settings/clean-urls where you'll be able to disable it.